# Javascript not showing in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript. I a reading this book with the following code. Somehow, it is not showing the date as I expect in my browser regardless of whether I use safari, or chrome or explorer.

Can someone help with what's wrong with it? I have tried moving the JavaScript to the body etc... Still the same problem.

Thanks

```
<html>    
<head>    
<title>My first web testing</title>
</head>
<body>
TESTING
<script type="text/javascript>
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getmonth()+ 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10)
    dd = '0' + dd;
        if(mm<10)
    mm = '0' + mm;
    today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    document.write("<b>" + today + "</b>");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the end quotation mark in the script declaration.

Should be

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the end quotation when you declare `<script type="text/javascript">`

Here's updated code:

```
<html>    
<head>    
<title>My first web testing</title>
</head>
<body>
TESTING
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getmonth()+ 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10)
    dd = '0' + dd;
        if(mm<10)
    mm = '0' + mm;
    today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    document.write("<b>" + today + "</b>");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Joel! I think your problem lies in two places, actually. When you were writing your `<script>` tag, you forgot an end quote. The second problem was in your function, `getMonth`. You forgot to capitalize Month. I hope this helps! Best of luck to you! (I'm still new to coding myself, and I know the struggle it's a little hard to get used to at first.)

```
<html>    
<head>    
<title>My first web testing</title>
</head>
<body>
TESTING
<script type="text/javascript"> //you left off an end quote here!
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+ 1; //don't forget to capitalize the second word!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10)
    dd = '0' + dd;
        if(mm<10)
    mm = '0' + mm;
    today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    document.write("<b>" + today + "</b>");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

As the mentioned your script tag is missing a quote but you also need to fix your `getmonth()` function... it should be `getMonth()`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My first web testing</title>
</head>
<body>
TESTING
<script type="text/javascript"> // add quote 
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+ 1; //getMonth
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10)
    dd = '0' + dd;
        if(mm<10)
    mm = '0' + mm;
    today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    document.write("<b>" + today + "</b>");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```